# Datetime has too many decimal places

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
// set properties on  builder (omitted for brevity)

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE WhenHire < @HireDate";
        SqlParameter hireDateParameter = new SqlParameter("@HireDate", DateTime.Now);
        command.Parameters.Add(hireDateParameter);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which shows up in SQL Profiler as:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE WhenHire < @HireDate',
                   N'@HireDate datetime',
                   @HireDate='2010-12-06 11:43:23.573'
```

How is the precision of the datetime parameter determined?  I've seen this have 7 digits after the decimal.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE WhenHire < @HireDate',
               N'@HireDate datetime',
               @HireDate='2010-12-06 11:43:23.5733125'
```

In that case, the statement fails to execute with this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to
>   datetime.

Comment: Can you post the table definition? Is `WhenHire` really of type datetime?

Comment: I would rather not post the entire table definition.  I can say for sure that WhenHire is a datetime type.  My main problem I want to figure out is why would 7 digits be generated after the decimal place in some situations?  I haven't been able to narrow down exactly what causes it and was looking for some suggestions.

Comment: Are you really recording a hire date down to the millisecond? Trim it and move on. Precision is determined by the producer of the server software you're using. It differs across all of the database technologies.

Comment: No, we don't do that, but that is missing the point.  For some reason, ADO.NET generated a SQL statement that put an extra 4 digits at the end of the parameter.  I was just wondering how that could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in the 2008 Profiler:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/08/13/sql-server-2008-profiler-pads-the-datetime-datatype-with-0s-when-tracing-for-a-ado-net-application.aspx

Comment: I posted this almost 2 years ago.  I can't even remember what I was working on. :)  Thanks for this info.

Answer (score 3):

Per Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), the T-SQL DateTime type has an accuracy of .000, .003, or .007 milliseconds.  Anything with more precision than that could cause that error.

Unless you really need accuracy down to the millisecond, I would give DateTime.Now a format string -- something like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" -- which would give you:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE WhenHire < @HireDate',
                   N'@HireDate datetime',
                   @HireDate='2010-12-06 11:43:23'
```

The .NET Framework is able to report on millisecond intervals down to seven decimal points, so if your source data is coming from DateTime.Now, you could potentially get up to seven decimal points passed in.

Comment: `select CAST('2010-12-06 11:43:23.573' as datetime)` works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, of course it does -- .573 is rounded to the nearest .003 seconds already.  In the question, the OP noted that he sees it go up to 7 digits of millisecond precision at times, which would cause the error he saw.

Comment: Yep. Sorry I didn't read the question properly. I thought the error message came about because of the supplied SQL which would only be explainable by `WhenHire` being `varchar` and containing an invalid datetime value.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend making sure you use a `SqlParameter` with a `DateTime` db type - try this code:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
// set properties on  builder (omitted for brevity)

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connection))
{
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE WhenHire < @HireDate";

    // make sure to have a SqlDbType.DateTime parameter!
    SqlParameter hireDateParameter = new SqlParameter("@HireDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    hireDateParameter.Value = DateTime.Now;

    command.Parameters.Add(hireDateParameter);

    // don't open the connection too early - this is early enough here!
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: connection.CreateCommand() will fail if the connection is not open.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Also from microsoft there are multiple date and time data types.  One is datetime2 which has increased accuracy and user-defined fractional second precision.

They give an example datetime2 with 7 digits of sub second precision.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was something strange with the client machine.  Not sure exactly what it was, but when we moved to another machine, it no longer added that extra precision.  Thanks for all the ideas.